# Access blob from directive in my controller (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want my controller to access a blob that's stored in a directive. Basically, I'm using this [Angular Audio Recorder](https://logbon72.github.io/angular-recorder/) and I want to save the resulting .wav file to disk (I'm using NWJS).

I know how to write the file, but I don't know how I can access the blob from my controller, I can't simply write `$scope.myBlob = audioModel`, since I get `"audioModel is not defined"`

Any ideas would be appreciated

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="audiotest">

<ng-audio-recorder id='audioInput' audio-model='recordedInput'>
  <!-- Start controls, exposed via recorder-->

  <div ng-if="recorder.isAvailable">
    <button ng-click="recorder.startRecord()" type="button" ng-disabled="recorder.status.isRecording">
        Start Record
    </button>
    <button ng-click="recorder.stopRecord()" type="button" ng-disabled="recorder.status.isRecording === false">
        Stop Record
    </button>
    <button ng-click="recorder.playbackRecording()" type="button"
            ng-disabled="recorder.status.isRecording || !recorder.audioModel">
        Play Back
    </button>

  </div>

  <div ng-if="!recorder.isAvailable">
    Message for users when recording is not possible.
  </div>
  <!-- End controls-->
</ng-audio-recorder>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on these lines in your markup, it looks like `audioModel` is a field on `recorder`, which is on your `$scope`.

```
<button ng-click="recorder.playbackRecording()" type="button"
        ng-disabled="recorder.status.isRecording || !recorder.audioModel">
    Play Back
</button>
```

Therefore, I wouldn't expect this to work:

```
$scope.myBlob = audioModel;
```

But I would expect this to do something:

```
$scope.myBlob = $scope.recorder.audioModel;
```

Comment: It does nothing, I just get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'audioModel' of undefined` According to the documentation: The controller for the ngAudioRecorder directive is exposed to your template (within the directive element) as an object recorder which can be used to control the recording and the playback..

Answer (score 0):

Got it, the blob is actually bound in the audio-model attribute - `audio-model='recordedInput'` , i.e. I can access it in the controller by `$scope.myBlob = $scope.recordedInput"`